# Show text in p tag if button is disabled vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to make a conditional p tag that appears only if a button is disabled I currently have this:

```
  <div class="finishTest">
    <button
      form="answerForm"
      type="submit"
      @click="getResult"
      :disabled="!this.enableButton()"
      :class="{
        disabledButton: !this.enableButton(),
      }"
    >
      {{ t("finish") }}
    </button>
    <p v-if="button == disabledButton">error</p>
  </div>
```

but this shows the p tag all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse with the style class variable. You can easily achieve this with `!enableButton`.

Try `<p v-if="!enableButton">error</p>` instead of `<p v-if="button == disabledButton">error</p>`

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.finishTest',
  data: {
    enableButton: true
  },
  methods: {
    getResult() {
        this.enableButton = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="finishTest">
  <button
          type="submit"
          @click="getResult"
          :disabled="!enableButton"
          >
    Click Me
  </button>
  <p v-if="!enableButton">error</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within this code line you use button and disabledButton.

 Where did you define **button** and **disabledButton** ?

```
 <p v-if="button == disabledButton">error</p>
```

Comment: I didnt define them I just wrote is as an example to try and show what im trying to achieve.

Comment: The answer below is the correct answer on how to do this. Try not to complicate things too much.